# whmcs module clientarea page per bought product

Tags: php, whmcs

so I have 2 modules one working(paid for not encrypted)learned a lot from it lets call this the **reference_module** and I have my own module which was a PHP page which I am rebuilding for WHMCS and it is almost working completly lets call it **created_module**.

the problem right now I have is the **reference_module** is called by when going to https://domainwhmcs.nl/clientarea.php?action=productdetails&id=0001&reference
which is working and shows what I want:

- the normal header
- normal sidebar
- normal footer
- and its own content in the main content area

it does this by using hooks having **ReferenceClientareaheaderoutput** and **ReferenceClientareapage** which works.

so now I tried to recreate this in **created_module** but when going to https://domainwhmcs.nl/clientarea.php?action=productdetails&id=0001&created which is working but shows me:

- its own content 
  just its own content but I want the same as in **Reference**.

I think if I am going to paste the code the post will be to long if needed maybe I can post specific parts.

Allread thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I actualy did solve it today you have to use javascript

```
jQuery.post("index.php",{"action":'dbinfo',"user":username,"serviceid":serviceid},
                    function(data){
                        jQuery(".main-content").html(data); 
                        jQuery("#tabs li").removeClass("active");
                        jQuery("#tabs li").eq(index).addClass("active");
```

and

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "dbinfo") {
```

this you do in your module hook if you need help you can contact me